# Network not working on XPS 13 9350 Intel ubuntu 16.04 after trying many things

Tags: networking, xps

My network does not work.

```
    lshw -C network
```

returns

```
    *-network               
    description: Ethernet interface
    physical id: 2
    logical name: enp0s20f0u2
    serial: be:f3:ee:09:86:60
    capabilities: ethernet physical
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.194 link=yes multicast=yes
```

because I'm tethering through USB. Basically my network card is not detected.

Another strange thing is that sometimes, when I first start my computer in the morning, the network and wifi connection works for a few minutes before suddenly stopping.

I tried disabling the secure boot in the BIOS, also

```
    sudo service network-manager restart
```

which has no effect. I also updated my kernel to 4.10, and updated the firmware, which did not solve the problem.

I wonder if the problem is hardware, any clues? I'd love to be sure it's hardware before buying a new card and changing it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try with a live session. Does it shows the same behavior?

Comment: Is it detected in the terminal command: `lspci`? Are there any clues in the log? `grep -e 0280 -e 8086 /var/log/syslog` or `grep -e 0280 -e 8086 /var/log/syslog.1`  ?  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.